# Pine Script Error: Add to Chart operation failed, reason: The limit is 50000

Tags: pine-script

I am creating a pine script which holds data of each stock(thousands of stocks)...Which results into the error of:Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Compiled script code is too long: 50668. The limit is 50000.Here is a small part of that code(It is the same code where i faced problem with).

```
//@version=4
study("PineTest", "", true)
srcHi = 0.00
srcLo = 0.00
if syminfo.ticker == "AMZN" 
srcHi:=2000.00 
srcLo:=1670.00 
if syminfo.ticker == "SPY" 
srcHi:=300.00 
srcLo:=210.00 
if syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" 
srcHi:=300.00 
srcLo:=170.00 
if syminfo.ticker == "MSFT"
srcHi:=210.00 
srcLo:=50.00 `

diff = srcHi - srcLo 

p1=plot(diff, title = "diff", color = #000000, transp= 0, offset=0, 
trackprice = true, linewidth = 2)
```

Is there any way to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's the limit of compiled tokens. You can sometimes work around it by functionalizing code, but once you're at that point, could be a good idea to review your project's design if you want to avoid dead ends.

Comment: Hello Sir, Is there any way i can add srcHigh and srcLow values in the same line without Replicating the functionality for srcLo. as you suggested in previous problem...